# How to get the foreign keys related to drop down only of that user in Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have `Category` model like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    '''
        Task for the wedding plans
    '''
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, default="bride")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Category(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    budget = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, help_text="Amount in dollars ($)")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
```

In my `forms.py`:

```
class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        exclude = ['user']

class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Task
       exclude = ['owner']


# views
form = TaskForm()
```

When I call `{{ form }}` in template, it shows categories created by all the users. But I want to show the category created by only the logged in user. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
form = TaskForm()
form.fields['owner'].queryset = Task.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
```

Or modify `TaskForm` as follow if it is used multiple times:

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Task
       exclude = ['owner']
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['owner'].queryset = Task.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

then, pass `request.user`:

```
form = TaskForm(request.user)
```

Comment: I am following your second approach. But I am getting `KeyError owner` error.

Comment: @user2032220, What happend if you replace `self.fields['owner'].queryset = Task.objects.filter(owner=user)` with `self.owner.queryset = Task.objects.filter(owner=user)` ?

Comment: `'TaskForm' object has no attribute 'owner'`